# finding a limit in a special form of a increasing sequence

Tags: analysis

I have tried my best to come up with some trick to solve this one but I'm stuck, any help would be very appreciated.

Question:

$\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence in which every outcome for a random $n$ gives us a positive output and for any $m$ and $n$ * $a_{n*m}>=n*a_m$

Prove if the set of $\{a_n/n;n=1,2,3,...\}$ is bounded then $a_n/n$ has a limit.

My attempts didn't work but my first thought was that because it's bounded then all I have to do is to prove it's increasing but I don't think it necessarily is so I tried the cauchy seq to say it's convergent but it didn't work.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it readable, but you might want to check it still says what you want

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "for a random $n$"? Here $n$ is a random variable? With what distribution?

Comment: i believe the sequence is unknown i apologize if i have confused you.also by "for a random n" i meant "an is positive for all n"